# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges never receives location on iOS8

Tags: gps, ios8, cllocationmanager

I am having a problem with `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in `iOS 8`

When using the following code, my iOS 8 physical device and simulator, never hit the `didUpdateLocations` method:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
        if (self.locationManager==nil) { self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; }
        self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            NSLog(@“requestAlwaysAuthorization”);
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
        NSLog(“didUpdateLocation”);
    }
```

If I replace `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` with `startUpdatingLocation`, the physical device receives one update (which is not what I was expecting) but the simulator continues to receive constant updates (which is what I was expecting, but not what I want).

Any ideas about how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. I also would prefer to use `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` instead of `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, but I read elsewhere that if I want to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, I need to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a description string in your plist file for key NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>With this mode, you will never miss location updates!</string>
```

Comment: I had `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` but did not realize there was a separate `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key. Thank you.